# how to integrate the information of two matrices using one matrix plot in R

Tags: r, matrix, plot

I have two matrices with the same dimension, column names and row names as shown below.

```
data(mtcars)
M <- cor(mtcars)

myMat<-matrix(runif(11*11), ncol=11) 

colnames(myMat) <- colnames(M)
rownames(myMat) <- rownames(M)
```

I want to visualize the two matrices using one matrix plot, like

```
corrplot(M, method = "circle")
```

I want to make a new graph, in which the color of circle is based on the `M` matrix and the size based on the `myMat` matrix.
Is there a way to implement this in R language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to long form and plot using ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)
long <- cbind(as.data.frame.table(M, responseName = "cor"), myMat = c(myMat))

ggplot(long, aes(Var1, Var2, col = cor, size = myMat)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_colour_gradient(low = "red", high = "blue") +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("")
```

giving:

[image: correlation plot]

Comment: Thank you, It is exactly what I wanted.